# What causes a foreign key mismatch error in sqlite database

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, foreign-keys, db-browser-sqlite

this is my student_table create query

```
CREATE TABLE "student_table" (
    "student_id"    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "name"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "gender"    TEXT NOT NULL,
    "year_admited"  INTEGER
);
```

this is for my year_table

```
CREATE TABLE "year_table" (
    "year"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "student_id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "class" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("year"),
    FOREIGN KEY("student_id") REFERENCES "student_table"("student_id")
);
```

and this for the terms_table

```
CREATE TABLE "terms_table" (
    "year"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "student_id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "term"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "fees"  INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY("term","year"),
    FOREIGN KEY("year") REFERENCES "year_table"("year"),
    FOREIGN KEY("student_id") REFERENCES "year_table"("student_id")
);
```

i successfully inserted a row in the student_table and in the year_table

i tried adding values to the terms table

```
INSERT INTO "main"."terms_table"
("year", "student_id", "term", "fees")
VALUES (2020, 1, 1, 900000);
```

but it gave this error

```
Error adding record. Message from database engine:

foreign key mismatch - "terms_table" referencing "year_table" (INSERT INTO 
"main"."terms_table"
("year", "student_id", "term", "fees")
VALUES (2020, 1, 1, 900000);)
```

I'm using dB browser for SQLite

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Required and Suggested Database Indexes](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_indexes):

> Usually, the parent key of a foreign key constraint is the primary key
> of the parent table. If they are not the primary key, then the parent
> key columns must be collectively subject to a UNIQUE constraint or
> have a UNIQUE index.

What you are doing wrong in your code is in the `CREATE` statement of `terms_table`:

```
FOREIGN KEY("student_id") REFERENCES "year_table"("student_id")
```

where you define the column `student_id` to reference the column `student_id` in `year_table` for which there is no `UNIQUE` constraint or index.
The column `student_id` in `year_table` just references the column `student_id` of `student_table`.

What you can do is define the column `student_id` of `terms_table` to reference the column `student_id` in `student_table`, which makes sense:

```
FOREIGN KEY("student_id") REFERENCES "student_table"("student_id")
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=d7ebcbb5be3eab890bb24c8ff1daf60b).